# how to paint button in windows-CE?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

i try to paint button in my C# windows-CE program.

in one device i Success to do it ( `button1.BackColor = Color.Red;`)

but in a nother device i see that the button in like win XP style - and

when i try to change the color it dosent Changed.

what can be the Reason ??

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the device has the XP skin component included (SYSGEN_XPSKIN) in the OS which overrides the standard button paint behavior.  If you want to paint the button, you need to either [create a different skin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms898231.aspx) for the device or get a new OS image that doesn't include the skin.

Comment: More sample on what, exactly?  You either have to remove the SYSGEN from the OS design in Platform builder (I can't really give you a "sample" on that, it's an OS component.  If you know how to use platform builder, it's one of the fundamental tasks you would do for almost anything).  Creating a skin is covered in the link I gave.  Getting a new OS would require contacting the device OEM (unless you are the OEM of course).

Comment: i need to delete any file from the Windows folder in the Device ?

Comment: It's not that simple.  Skinning support is baked into gwes.  If you want to remove it, you need a new OS image.  Only the OEM can provide that.